# remove rows with duplicate values in single column and older timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, duplicates

Suppose I have a csv file where in first column are forecast dates, in second are issued date, and in third column are the forecast values:

```
forecast,issued,temp
2016021700,2016021702,5.3
2016021706,2016021702,6.3
2016021712,2016021702,8.6
2016021718,2016021702,5.1
2016021700,2016021703,5.4
2016021706,2016021703,6.4
```

In python, I would like to automatically remove those rows with the same forecast date and older issued date. The output should be in date/time order according to forecast date. The expected result is:

```
forecast,issued,temp
2016021700,2016021703,5.4
2016021706,2016021703,6.4
2016021712,2016021702,8.6
2016021718,2016021702,5.1
```

Any help appreciate~

**SOLUTION:** I solved this using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='forecast',keep='last')
df = df.sort(['forecast'],ascending=True)
df.to_csv('out.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: You should try something yourself, and come here with code, if it needs help

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I really do not know where to start and all my efforts were just too far from what I expected,and not worthy to post here. If I will get closer I will share. For this moment any suggestion will help.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to sort your file according to issued date column, and them use `groupby` to remove consecutive duplicates:

```
from itertools import groupby

# open a csv_reader for the file
data = sorted(csv_reader, key=lambda cols: make_date(cols[1]))
no_dups_data = []
for key, group in groupby(data, key=lambda cols: cols[1]):
    no_dups_data.append(next(group))
```

Where `make_date` should parse the date in the format you have. You should be able to use the `datetime` module for that.

You could also avoid sorting using some `dict`s, but that solution would be quite a bit more involved (but it could be a good exercise).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. It gave me some ideas about sorting. My final solution is using pandas (code below)